# Icons in bootstrap tooltip

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

Does anybody knows if it's possible to add icons in bootstrap's tooltip ?
The only info I've found on bootstrap tooltip is how to customize its colors or how to add some animation on it with animate.css
Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey this is pretty easy to do. You will need to add the following attributes to the element that includes your tooltip. First data-html="true". After you do that you will be able to insert HTML into the title="". That should provide you with what you need. Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/CodeBroJohn/pen/ORyXqa) example. In my example I left the tooltip static so you can see it. `<button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-trigger="manual" data-placement="right" title="<button>Facebook</button>" class="btn btn-default" id="example">example</button>`

Comment: Thanks CodeBroJohn didn't know that I could add html into the title.It becomes easy to add font awesome icons in the tooltip :-) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QKjKvj

Comment: No Problem, I went back and edited the code and added the font awesome facebook icon. Glad I could help. Just an FYI font awesome has classes that allow you to make the icon bigger as well in my example I used fa-5x.